# Animated image causing warning of "Can only update a mounted or mounting component"

Tags: reactjs, react-native

In one of my screens, I have this warning that I'm not sure how to fix.

[image]

I think it is due to an animated image background becuase once I comment out the `animated.timing()` function the warning disappers

I first initialized the image source and animated values in the constructor like below:

```
this.backgroundImage = require('../assets/images/graidenttPastel.jpg'); 
this.backgroundImageWidth = resolveAssetSource(this.backgroundImage).width;
this.translateXValue1 = new Animated.Value(-1);
this.translateXValue2 = new Animated.Value(0);
this.animationLength = 20000;
```

I used the `Animated.timing` function like below:

```
 translateXFirstHalfLoop() {
    var phoneWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width;
    this.translateXValue1.setValue(-1);
    this.setState({translateXValue2Offset: this.backgroundImageWidth});
    Animated.timing(
      this.translateXValue1,
      {
        toValue: -this.backgroundImageWidth,
        duration: this.animationLength/2,
        easing: Easing.linear
      }
    ).start(()=>this.translateXSecondHalfLoop())
  }


  translateXSecondHalfLoop() {
    this.translateXValue1.setValue(this.backgroundImageWidth);
    this.setState({translateXValue2Offset: -this.backgroundImageWidth});
    Animated.timing(
      this.translateXValue1,
      {
        toValue: 0,
        duration: this.animationLength/2,
        easing: Easing.linear
      }
    ).start(()=>this.translateXFirstHalfLoop())
  }
```

Then I called the functions in `componentDidMount()` :'

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.translateXFirstHalfLoop()
}
```

My `render()` method:

```
  render() {
    this.translateXValue2 = Animated.add(this.translateXValue1, this.backgroundImageWidth);

    return (
      <SafeAreaView
        style={[{backgroundColor: THEME_COLOR, flex: 1}]}
        forceInset={{ bottom: 'never' }}>
        <Animated.Image
          style={{
            position: 'absolute',
            left: this.translateXValue1,
             }}
          resizestate={Image.resizeMode.cover}
          source={this.backgroundImage}
        />
        <Animated.Image
          style={{
            position: 'absolute',
            left: this.translateXValue2,
             }}
          resizestate={Image.resizeMode.cover}
          source={this.backgroundImage}
        />
        ...
```

I have followed tutorials to set the animated components up and I'm not calling setState, replaceState for an unmonted component. What did I do wrong with this implementation?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but these animation functions will call each other back & forth infinitely won't they? With the `start()` of each other at the end calling the other.

Comment: @MattyK14 yes but I have seen implementations like this where a function calls itself at start(), so that the animation is in an infinite loop. Should I somehow stop it?

Comment: Yes, you're calling `setState` in those functions, therefore it infinitely tries to set the state. Then you unmount the component, but `setState` is still occurring thus giving you this warning. Which by the way is a crash in production, but for some reason only a warning in debug.

Comment: @MattyK14 How should I end the loop. I checked through the `Animated` API and didn't see any method to stop an `Animated.timing()` function. Also does `Animated` API really uses `setState`? I thought it uses something else than the component's `state` to update animated components.

Comment: you're calling `setState`: `this.setState({translateXValue2Offset: this.backgroundImageWidth});` & `this.setState({translateXValue2Offset: -this.backgroundImageWidth});`

Comment: It appears that you can call `stop()` on `Animated` API. Maybe you create something like `this.firstHalfAnimation` = `Animated.timing(...` for each. Then call `this.firstHalfAnimation.start(() => this.secondHalfAnimation.start())` in the `componentDidMount` and then in the `componentWillUnmount` you call `this.firstHalfAnimation.stop()` for both. May or may not work.